# ionic plugin open native popup handle back button cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

guys please help me to find out solution 
how to disable back button in ionic cordova app if native popup (android popup) is opened.

I have used

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e) {
     // android hardware back button was hit
}, 100);
```

Which is working fine in cordova app but a problem occurs when I call plugin and native popup opens I cant get the backButton event. 
I am tried to override the backButton in native (plugin code) by using

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed (final CallbackContext callbackContext){
        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, "Back Button"));
    }
```

but it shows Method does not override from its superclass.
Can anyone help me to find the solution of this.

Comment: You have to do like when native popup opens back must be disable am i right?

Comment: @Paresh Gami Yes

Comment: Can you please tell me which plugin you are using?

Comment: custom dual sim selection plugin